# Showing content if user have right role. Spring Java Security

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-security, backend

I have a question. Using Spring Security i can permit to view pages if user have right role. My question is:

if I have 2 roles for the example:

- MOD
- DEF

on the page we can see items in a table. If user have DEF rights only display items and names, but if he have a MOD rights in right site of the item should shows 2 buttons.

Can i do it in Spring Security? I know that i can do it using session and remember user role

Red can see only user with mod rights

[image]

Comment: Sure, you can tell the frontend which roles the user has and the frontend displays the buttons accordingly - or you go the way of HATEOAS and pass the links to the frontend that the user is allowed to click. Where exactly are you struggling?

Comment: @luk2302 ooo thanks you, I using Thymeleaf and found this "Spring Security Dialect", and using "sec:authorize="hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN')"" i can show my elements only to user with role admin